# How to deploy PostgresSQL python app which is hosted in google cloud?

Tags: python, postgresql, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, psycopg2

I have problem with deploying python app which writes down additional info to sql database. Postgres SQL is hosted in google cloud and for connecting to it i'm using credential files and invoking it through cmd in path with stored json. Command
In powershell

```
>>CD "path where stored"
>>cloud_sql_proxy -credential_file=./credentials.json -instances="[PROJECT-ID]:[REGION]:[INSTANCE-NAME]=tcp:5435"
```

The question, how i will deploy it google app engine, And how can i call function with json. without typing it into cmd?

Answer (score 0):

I see you are using the Cloud SQL Proxy to connect to your PostgreSQL instance.

In the specific case of App Engine the public facing documentation offers clear [instructions](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/postgres/connect-app-engine-standard) and code on how to achieve this.

You basically need to provide the App Engine's service account the correct permissions (the recommended role will be Cloud SQL Client) and adapt the code in your Python application to connect to the instance.

The link shared shows how to use the [SQL alchemy](https://www.sqlalchemy.org/) to achieve this connection for both Public and Private IP.